# Bootstrap drop down pull-left not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried putting pull-left on everything and whatever I do the drop down menu containing 'Edit' and 'Destroy' falls to the right meaning I get nasty scrollbars appearing.

**HAML** version:

```
.btn-group
  %button{ :class => 'btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' }
    %span.icon-cog
  %ul.dropdown-menu
    %li= link_to 'Edit', '#'
    %li= link_to 'Destroy', '#'
```

**HTML** version:

```
<div class='btn-group'>
  <button class='btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
    <span class='icon-cog'></span>
  </button>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu nav pull-left'>
    <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Destroy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

As of v3.1.0 pull-left has been deprecated..

Instead use `dropdown-menu-right`

[See here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment)

Answer (score 8):

Use `pull-right` instead of `pull-left` and menu will be shown on the left.

Answer (score 4):

dropdown `pull-left` not working for `dropdown-menu`, but working for `dropdown-submenu`

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">
  <a href="#" >Branch</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Create Branch</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Edit Branch</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Set Branch Status</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ms7US/4/)

Comment: I see. I can also get it working on dropdown-submenu but not dropdown-menu. So this won't work for me. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Suggestion: Accept the answer and bug-report it :-)